# Robot framework | Can't click on a react generated element

Tags: reactjs, robotframework

I cannot click on a element that was generated by React, It is a simple div here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWYCh.png)

I have tried original method from robot framework to locate and press the div.

This is what i tried

```
Click Element       //div[@class="sc-pyfCe gFWPAl"]
Click Element       //div[@id="root"]
```

I am waiting 8s after the page is loaded but it still says:

> Element with locator '//div[@class="sc-pyfCe gFWPAl"]' not found.